# right in sql is not working on the where clause

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2, where-clause

When I have this `where` clause

```
WHERE MT.Media = 'Telephone' AND
LEN('0557500007')>8 and [MediaValue]='0557500007'
```

I got one row in sql management studio

but when i make this `where`

```
WHERE MT.Media = 'Telephone' AND
LEN('0557500007')>8 and RIGHT([MediaValue],8) =RIGHT('0557500007',8)
```

I got empty result, why please?

from the first `where` clause, you can see that I do that this value `0557500007`, but why it is not showing when I apply the second `where` clause?

Comment: have you `trim` the values while checking ?

Comment: @POHH no, why would I? as I told you, from the first `where` clause, i got a row, which means that I do have exactly the same value in the database

Comment: What is the value in the [MediaValue] field? If it isn't '05575000' you can't get any results

Comment: @timfranklin the value is `0557500007`. I can see it in the sql management studio, and you can be sure from it because the first `where` clause is giving me a row

Comment: the same query when tried with different values . i got it right.

Comment: @POHH sorry but i am asking about why it is not working in that way. However, I can't use like, this is a query for one customer, i can't use like at all.

Comment: @POHH sorry I didn't get your last comment, which is `the same query when tried with different values . i got it right.`

Comment: ok . thats fair enough. but when i run same query in `SSMS` `select * from production.product where right('R-5381',4)= right(productnumber,4)` i got it right. you can also check if you have `adventureworks` db in place

Comment: Couple of things, do a LEN(MediaValue) to verify it returns the correct number of characters and check the datatype that will determine if you need to use the trim and be nice to OP that is trying to assist

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd the type is `nvarchar 256 `

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli and what is its content with just select [MediaValue] ?

Comment: @ConradLotz the `len` is `10`, which is correct

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd If I do `select mediavalue` without a where clause, i got a lot of values but when I but the where clause, I got this value `0557500007`

Comment: there was an answer, and it works, using the `rtrim` solved the problem,

Comment: anyone write an answer to accept it please. @POHH you the first one who said that, please write your answer

Comment: Strange, RTRIM should solve the problem only for types CHAR and NCHAR, not NVARCHAR. So I still wonder what the actual problem is. How come the strings are considered equal, but their rightmost eight characters aren't?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I really don't know, and I worry about this thing. I am afraid that other problem could happen after deploy the service on client server. can we know the problem? do you need other infomration?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the slightest idea, what is happening here. Fixed length data types would have been an answer, but as this isn't the case here, I am completely out of clues. It even looks like a bug in the DBMS to me. Sorry, I cannot help you further.

Comment: Found it. Look here: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626/en-us . SQL Server treats 'abc' and 'abc   ' as equals and claims this behavior to be standard-compliant. This is something one has to be aware of, when working with SQL-Server. I've posted an according answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE MT.Media = 'Telephone' AND
LEN('0557500007')>8 and RIGHT(rtrim([MediaValue]),8) =RIGHT('0557500007',8)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL-Server pads a string with blanks in order to compare it with another. They claim this behavior to be standard-compliant (at least with SQL-92): https://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626/en-us .

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2,
>   , General rules #3) on how to compare strings
>   with spaces. The ANSI standard requires padding for the character
>   strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before
>   comparing them. The padding directly affects the semantics of WHERE
>   and HAVING clause predicates and other Transact-SQL string
>   comparisons. For example, Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and
>   'abc ' to be equivalent for most comparison operations.

So unlike other DBMS, SQL-Server treats '0557500007' and '0557500007    ' as equals. It seems, hence, your column value has trailing spaces. Use RTRIM to remove these:

```
right(rtrim(MediaValue]),8)
```